# code change for each version update

Tags: c++, c

I just downloaded the open source code(sphinx) and modified some of the *.cpp and *.c files inorder to achieve the result which i required.

Now for each version update,need to go and modify the code again and again...

Is there any possible ways to achieve this without touching the source code directly?

Can someone help me in this regard...?

Comment: Patch: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_(Unix)

Comment: http://jungels.net/articles/diff-patch-ten-minutes.html

Comment: user1937198::I tried the step which u said but it replaces the code straight away.....Incase if the updated version has some code changes,it doesn't bothers,it will straight away copy the modified code what i have....How to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Use a version control system. For example GIT. Just create a branch with your changes, and merge each new version of the library into your branch. This will preserve your changes and show you any possible conflict easily.

Or if the project is already an open source project hosed on a GIT server, just crate your private fork from it.