# Issues while running the patch in linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, sphinx

I tried this steps in order to create a patch

[code change for each version update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23061633/code-change-for-each-version-update/23062459?noredirect=1#23062459)

jungels.net/articles/diff-patch-ten-minutes.html

- Can able to create a patch
- if i run the patch,it replaces the code straight away.....Incase if the updated version has some code changes,it doesn't bothers,it will straight away copy the modified code what i have....

  How to overcome this issue?(ie::Need to have the updated version code changes also)

Answer (score 0):

Use version control. As already noted.

If you really taking about sphinxsearc, its available via SVN
https://code.google.com/p/sphinxsearch/source/checkout

So checkout a copy. Make any changes as needed to your local working copy. Can then just run `svn update` which will download the latest changes from teh repository, but **wont** discard your local edits.

(Can also use SVN to create 'patch' files directly. to keep a record of your changes against the current version of sphinx)